# Estimates for the Sobolev inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

How to prove the Sobolev estimate:

If $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^N$, then
for any $q>1$
$$ 
\|u\|_{L^{q}(\Omega)} \leq C|\Omega|^{1/q} q^{1- 1/N}\| \nabla  u \|_{L^{N} (\Omega)} ; \forall u\in W^{1, N}_{0} (\Omega),
$$
where the constant $C>0$ depends on $N$ only.

Comment: You have both $n$ and $N$. are they the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: I believe the power of q is correct. But the constant should not depend on u.

Comment: Check if my editing is correct.

Comment: This follows from Moser--Trudinger inequality.

Comment: But I believe still it is provable without using Moser--Trudinger inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$ p = \frac{qN}{q+N}, $$
then
$$
q = \frac{pN}{N-p}
$$
Therefore, since, $u$ is compactly supported in $\Omega$, by the sharp Sobolev inequality of Aubin and Talenti (see [Talenti's paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d53/f688bb8da8ba85e43ca2a6d24b2af88cbb03.pdf)) and the Holder inequality,
$$
\|u\|_{L^q(\Omega)} \le C(N,p)\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le
C(N,p)|\Omega|^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{N}}\|\nabla u\|_{L^N(\Omega)} 
= C(N,p)|\Omega|^{\frac{1}{q}}\|\nabla u\|_{L^N(\Omega)}, $$
where
$$
  C(N,p) = \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}}N^{-1/p}\left(\frac{p-1}{N-p}\right)^{1-1/p}
  \left\{\frac{\Gamma(1+N/2)\Gamma(N)}{\Gamma(N/p)\Gamma(1+N-N/p)}\right\}^{1/N}
$$
It is now straightforward to check that if $q \rightarrow \infty$, then $p\rightarrow N$ and $C(N,p) \sim q^{1-1/N}$.